# Howto get GoogleDrive Quota(remaining available size) with GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, quota

I use only GoogleApiClient on Android app.
I can not get my GoogleDrive Quota Usage(total/available/etc..).
As Googling..., may be DriveService(com.google.api.services.drive.Drive) is possible... but I am not use that......

How to get GoogleDrive quota info?

(Note) Here is my GoogleApiClient builder.

```
GDApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .setAccountName(token)
                .build();
```

Comment: I found this example code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get#examples) which uses `about.getQuotaBytesUsed()` and `about.getQuotaBytesTotal()`. I think this is what you are looking for. Also, you can always look at the quota/remaining size in the Developer's Console manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (AFAIK), there is no equivalent of `getQuotaBytesTotal(), getQuotaBytesUsed()` in [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).

So, the only way to get this info (and other functionalities not present - like `thumbnails`, ...), is to add the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) Api. Still, be sure you use this mix carefully, you may run into many latency / timing issues.

There are a few pre-requisites for accomplishing this:

1/ make sure you include the following jars in your project:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
...
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
```

2/ you will need an additional permission in your manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

3/ You have to get the `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive` service and query it after GDAA's `onConnected()` callback, like so:

```
private static GoogleApiClient mGAC;
private static com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGooSvc;

static boolean init(Activity context) {
  if (context != null) try {

    mGooSvc = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
      new GsonFactory(),
      GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
        context.getApplicationContext(),
        Collections.singletonList(com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)
      )
    ).build();

    mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
      .addApi(Drive.API)
      // ... additional APIs
      .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGooSvc.about().get().execute();
                System.out.println("Total quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesTotal());
                System.out.println("Used quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesUsed());
              } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
              //} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException uraIOEx) {
              //  // standard authorization failure - user fixable
              //} catch (GoogleAuthIOException gaIOEx) {
              //  // usually PackageName /SHA1 mismatch in DevConsole
              //} catch (IOException e) {
              //  if (e instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException) {
              //    if (404 == ((GoogleJsonResponseException) e).getStatusCode()) {
              //      // '404 not found' in FILE scope, consider connected
              //    }
              //  }
              //} catch (Exception e) {
              //  // "the name must not be empty" indicate
              //  // UNREGISTERED / EMPTY account in 'setSelectedAccountName()' above
              //}
            }
          }).start();
        }
      })
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult rslt) {
          // perform standard authorization dance
        }
      })
      .build();

    mGAC.connect();

    return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  return false;
}
```

Notice, that I commented out the error / authorization handling for the REST's `execute()` method. It is because the GDAA's `connect()/onConnected()/onConnectionFailed()` handles the authorization already (if the scopes are identical).

Good Luck

Comment: thanks your apply, I test it, but I get error, 'cannot resolve method about.getQuotaBytesTotal()'. so i am searching other methods....

Comment: It works on my system, look at the JARs and imports.

Comment: yes, i placed JARs in my app's build.gradle, but not works in my case. the error message(return json) is "message": "Invalid field selection quotaBytesTotal" and  "reason": "invalidParameter". because I called method this, "com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGDSvc.about().get().setFields("quotaBytesTotal").execute();", but this line is problem... i dont know why...

Comment: Success, I try this, "com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = mGDSvc.about().get().setIncludeSubscribed(false).setMaxChangeIdCount(1L).setStartChangeId(1L).setFields("quotaBytesTotal,quotaBytesUsed").execute();"

Comment: Doesn't the original 'mGDSvc.about().get().execute()' work as well?